# Quota exceeded error when create new profile with GC Talent Solution

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-talent-solution

Step to reproduce: Go to this site, https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/job-search/docs/reference/rest/v4beta1/projects.tenants.profiles/create, make a POST request with a valid tenant name, to create a new profile.

Get error: `"8 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED: Quota exceeded for quota metric 'quota metric that handles profile write requests' and limit 'quota metric that handles profile write requests per minute' of service 'jobs.googleapis.com' for consumer 'project_number:XXXXXXXXX'."`

My current usage is just 100+ post/put/delete requests per month, and if I remember correctly, free tie in Google Cloud allows thousands of requests per 100 seconds.

My billing account was setup and the card is valid. I can create companies, tenants as normal.

[image]

Please help.

Comment: Open a support ticket with Google Cloud Support. There is nothing that we can do for you. The error message is clear, you have a quota problem that you are exceeding.

Comment: No it is not clear. I already said my current usage is significant low, just 1-2 requests per day, and I never create any profile before, so unless the quota is 0 or I miss something, this is not a clear message. In the quota page, it still show I used 0% of quota. If the message is clear, it should show 100% and force me pay the bill before using it. I didn't receive any bill.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a vendor issue that requires the vendor to provide assistance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As John Hanley commented quota issues are usually handled by the Cloud Support team and should be addressed opening a support ticket. However, this case refers to Cloud Talent Solution Profile Search which as stated in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/talent-solution/profile-search/docs/?authuser=1&hl=id) at this moment is in 'Closed Beta' state, meaning that it doesn't allow new candidates.

In order to use this feature you will have to wait until it's released to the public or the Beta is opened for new candidates.

Comment: Thanks Joaquim, I didn't notice the "Closed" part.